Error publishing in Google Play: The version 1 code has already been used. Try another code
I have uploaded version 1.0.9 of my Android application, developed in .NET Core and MAUI, for review. It was rejected by some reason I have fixed.
Now, I can upload version 1.0.10 but the error is shown:

The version 1 code has already been used. Try another code.


How can I publish version 1.0.10 to relaunch review?
Thanks

1.0.10 is the versionName.
There should be a configuration named versionCode inside you project. You should find it and increase the number (2 for example)


Just for extra info-  it doesn't matter what the version code is the only rules are that each build has its own version, and that the version code must only increase, never decrease.  There are no rules on the version name at all, it can be anything.  The version name is displayed in the store, the code is only used internally.
